# H2 database not finding information after application is restarted

Tags: spring, hibernate, h2, create-table

I have created a spring app with this application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.schema=schema-h2.sql
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:JMeterMaid
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

 #Hibernate Configuration:  
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect 
hibernate.show_sql=true  
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update

entitymanager.packages.to.scan=com.spr.model
```

and this schema-h2.sql file

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RunEntity (ID INTEGER IDENTITY,TestNumber INTEGER NOT NULL, TestName varchar(50) NOT NULL, ENVIRONMENT VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, Source VARCHAR(50), Date TIMESTAMP, RESULTFILES BLOB);
```

I thought that the line CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS would make the program able to find information from the database after the application stopped running and was restarted.  However none of the information can be found once the application is running again.  What can i do to save information and access it during multiple runs of the application?

Answer (score 0):

You used a relative path in the database URL:

- `jdbc:h2:file:JMeterMaid` (relative to the current working directory)

This will no longer be supported in future version of H2. It means, the database file is stored in the current working directory. When you start your program in another directory, a new database is created there.

To solve the problem, use an absolute path, or a path relative to the current user home directory, for example:

- `jdbc:h2:file:/data/JMeterMaid` (absolute path)
- `jdbc:h2:file:~/data/JMeterMaid` (relative to the current user home directory)

Comment: Thanks you for your response.  Although it is a good idea to use an absolute path, my problem is that my program does not recover database information from prior uses, not that it cannot recover data when i change the directory.  Thanks

Comment: OK, it might not be the solution in your case, but others that use a similar database URL might run into this problem.